# Is it possible to declare a div section an later in the same document provide it with data etc?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to declare a div section an later in the same document provide it with data etc?? 
The following PSUEDO code might explain the question...

```
<div name="xyz" style="...">
   <!-- Empty -->
</div>

< ... INTO "xyz" >
   <p> Hello </p>
   <?php echo "Hello again."; ?>
</ ... >
```

Regards

Comment: yes ... just you have to write codes

Comment: I am doing my site without any client side scripting if that is what you had in mind? My whiches doing somthing like the above is mostly for structuring the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pretty much like you just did:

```
<div>

<?php 
  //this part is not visible inside <div> when the website is loaded
  echo "but this part is visible inside the div tag"; 
 ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I would more like to have it something like
    <div> <?php
      echo file_get_contents("#embedded_in_this_.php");
    ?></div>
where the data is actually somewhere in the same doc.

Comment: <div> <?php include_once('#embedded_in_this_.php') ?> </div>  //should be enough

Comment: Yes but that would yield another http GET which i like to avoid :) I know my example doing just that but it was for illustrating what I need.
Perhaps. ...
<div><?php do_function(); ?></div> ...  <?php function do_function(){ echo "my actions"; } ... is the simple solution? All is really about organising and avoid cluttering...

Comment: I must admit, i'm not sure what your goal is. But i'm gonna guess. You mentioned: "...and later in the same document provide it with data" and your example lookes a bit like a chat window or blog. If you want to populate more -/ update data inside DIV  "after" the site has finished loading (remeber php only executes on the server before site has loaded in browser!). There is only two ways: using JavaScript to send an ajax request to server and sending response data to DIV element, or reload the entire page using form element - sending a submit request containing request data in URL string.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about keeping the code clean and really nothing else. I am an oldie when it comes to coding and one thing I really have learned is the importance of well structured code. It simplifies design and maintainance and ofcause debugging looking for strange behaviors et.c. In C-code one usually have an objectoriented approach or divide and conquer. One simple rule one learn on the early stages is to design the code so one can have a good overview. I.e. don't have several hundred lines of code in one pair of braces. Also as an embedded developer developing on limited resources it is allways in my mind what resources I have and that includes bandwith and latencies implied. So I want to avoid the client to have to fetch to many documents html, php, images or what else needed. It can not always be avoided but.. So have a look on this..

`<div style=".......">
  <div style="...">
     CONTENTS A
  </div
  <div style="...">
     CONTENTS B
  </div>
  <div style="...">
     CONTENTS C
  </div>
</div>`

It sure looks ok and it is easy to overview. But it it the same if the contents uses 50-100 rows of code? No it will not! Well no problem lets include the contents from another file shall we? Yes that works but.. Wont we get way to many files instead in the end? A real mess? For me it is about avoiding this mess. Så I can rewrite the code above for example to

```
<div style=".......">
  <div style="...">
    <?php produce_code_A();?>
  </div
  <div style="...">
    <?php produce_code_B();?>
  </div>
  <div style="...">
    <?php produce_code_C();?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
  function produce_code_A(){ ... }
  function produce_code_B(){ ... }
  function produce_code_C(){ ... }
?>
```

Thats looks nice doesn't it?
Yes it does but then on the other hand it will mean that I have to "echo out HTML" code if I for example need a table or list or what ever. It would still be a mess :/ So to finalize is that I am after is a better solution. Fetching alot of small files isn't a desired solution. For those who are familiar with C/C++ and similar I can say that a use of #define would be excellent. That would look something like.

```
 #define MYLIST_A <ul> .... </ul>
 #define MYLIST_B <ul> .... </ul>
 #define MYLIST_C <ul> .... </ul>
 <div style=".......">
   <div style="...">
    MYLIST_A
   </div
   <div style="...">
     MYLIST_B
   </div>
   <div style="...">
     MYLIST_C
   </div>
 </div>
```

Hopefully this makes it much clearer what I want and what I am seeking? Does it?